# How to get DynamicRecord field value, use that for matching, then update DynamicRecord

Tags: scala, aws-glue

New to Scala with AWS Glue. What I'm trying to do is to get a value for a field on the DynamicRecord coming in so I can use that to match with, then update the record, then return it.

In the code below, I'd like to first get the field value with this: `rec => rec.getField(col)`

So I can test the value prior to going on to match.

Here's what I have currently and it works as is.

```
    def doSomething(col: String): DynamicRecord => DynamicRecord = 
    { 
     
      rec => rec.getField(col) match 
      {
        case Some(s: String) => 
        {
           //do something with s to the record (rec)
        }
        case default => do something with default case to the record (rec)
      }
      rec
    }
```

Note since I'm directly doing the match with `rec` then I have it available to further update it.

But I need to get the value first then match and finally return the changed record. Something akin to this below. But because I'm using the field value for the matching, I no longer have reference to the `rec` inside the case.

```
    def doSomething(col: String): DynamicRecord => DynamicRecord = 
    { 
      var fldVal: String = ""
      rec => fldVal = rec.getField(col)

      fldVal match 
      {
        case Some(s: String) => 
        {
           //do something to the record with s
        }
        case default => //do something to the record with default case
      }
      rec //need to return record here
    }
```

How can I get the field value from rec first then have a reference to rec so I can change it and return it?

Errors I've received are, missing parameter type, type mismatch.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is a bit confusing. It looks like what you're after is something like this.

```
def doSomething(col: String): DynamicRecord => DynamicRecord =
  rec => {
    rec.getField(col) match {
      case Some(s: String) =>
        //do something to the record with s
      case default =>
        //do something to the record with default case
    }
    rec //need to return record here
  }
```

If so, I might recommend the following simplification.

```
def doSomething(col: String): DynamicRecord => DynamicRecord =
  rec => rec.getField(col).fold {
    //return rec modified with default case
  } { s =>
    //return rec modified with s
  }
```